# Python unittest mock: mocking a class function via a parameterized class object?

Tags: mocking, python-unittest, magicmock

In `lib/thing.py`:

```
class Class(object):
    def class_function1(self):
```

In `app/thing.py`:

```
def function2(class_object):
    class_object.class_function1()
```

In `test/test_thing.py`, I want to patch `lib.thing.Class.class_function1` when function2 is called with a mocked Class() object to raise an `AttributeError` which should just perc up to `test_function2` unimpeded. Something like this (which doesn't work):

```
def test_function2(self):
    mocked_class = mock.MagicMock(name="class", spec_set=lib.thing.Class)
    with assertRaises(AttributeError):
        with patch ('lib.thing.Class.class_function1', side_effect=AttributeError):
            function2(mocked_class)
```

Comment: Dropping the patch and just setting `mocked_class.class_function1.side_effect = AttributeError` raises the `AttributeError` correctly when `class_function1` gets hit in `function2`, but `assertRaises` doesn't acknowledge it. Hm. One step closer or one step sideways ...

Answer (score 1):

I dropped patch entirely and worked with side_effect in the mocked class object.

```
def test_function2(class_object):
    mocked_class = mock.MagicMock(name="class", spec_set=lib.thing.Class)
    mocked_class.class_function1.side_effect = AttributeError("sorry for the pseudo code")
    with assertRaises(AttributeError):
         function2(mocked_class)
```